# How to get maximum value of value1 from table where value1 and value2 fields ignoring value2 field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with column1 = date, column2 = A/B, column3 = id. I want result where latest date comparing to Id should be with B in column2, Ignore if A

Table

```
C1        C2    C3
10/6/19   A      1
12/6/19   B      1
13/6/19   A      2
09/6/19   A      3
03/6/19   B      1
04/6/19   B      2
12/6/19   B      4
03/6/19   A      5
06/6/19   B      3
```

Expected result

```
C3 1 - Valid . Because last value of latest date is B
C3 4 - Valid . Because last value of latest date is B
C3 3 - Invalid. Because last value of latest date is A
```

Comment: what you've tried for that?

Comment: I tried select c3, max(c1), c2 from table where c2 = B and c3 not in (select c3 from table where c2= A) group by c3. But it doesn't check values where latest date with c2=B

Comment: well edit the question with the query you've tried

Comment: c2 should be B in latest date. Ignore if c2=A in latest date. in single query

Comment: What should be expected if for a latest date, A & B both present?

Comment: If for Id = 1 . list of values are A B B . it'll ignore because A is in latest date. If for Id = 2. list of values are B A B . It'll be valid because B is in latest date

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated subquery

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b2b88a836151090c7762a65ce00bfe2b)**

```
select * from t1 a
where c1 =(select max(c1) from t1 b where a.c3=b.c3 )
and c2='B'
```

OUTPUT:

```
c1         c2   c3
2012-06-19  B   1
2012-06-19  B   4
```

Comment: Sorry . but it is taking records where A is in latest date. It should ignore that Id if A is in latest date. Only take records where B is in latest date.

Comment: @SanketPatel, in which case it's taking that? show your case

Comment: I got result where it was A B B. It should ignore that Id

Comment: from my understanding, it should not, and I've already provided a demo you can check there also you can fill your original dataset there to show actually in which case it is occurring @SanketPatel

Comment: I cannot show it . Sorry . but im also applying date > c1 in both query. Can you tell me if i should apply it in both query or just 1

Answer (score 0):

Assumin c1 column is valid date  You could try using a subquery for max(c1)

```
select  * 
from my_table m 
inner join  (
  select  id,  max(c1) max_c1 
  from my_table  
  group by id  
) t on t.max_c1 = m.c1 and m.c2='A' and t.id = m.id
```

Or if you need  also the id not matching you coul append uisng UNION

```
select  * 
from my_table m 
inner join  (
  select  id,  max(c1) max_c1 
  from my_table  
  group by id  
) t on t.max_c1 = m.c1 and m.c2='A'
select  * 
from my_table m 
inner join  (
  select  id,  max(c1) max_c1 
  from my_table  
  group by id  
) t on t.max_c1 = m.c1 and m.c2='A' and t.id = m.id 

union 

select  max(c1), c2, id
  from my_table where id not in (
  select id 
  from my_table m 
  inner join  (
    select  id,  max(c1) max_c1 
    from my_table  
    group by id  
  ) t on t.max_c1 = m.c1 and m.c2='A'
select  * 
  from my_table m 
  inner join  (
    select  id,  max(c1) max_c1 
    from my_table  
    group by id  
  ) t on t.max_c1 = m.c1 and m.c2='A' and t.id = m.id 
)
group by c2, id
```

Comment: It is only taking values where c2=A . I need c2=B with latest date and ignore if c2=A in latest date

Comment: Can you provide proper query. I am not able to understand this whole query

Comment: Should i take this whole query ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the `c3` values with an indicator, you can use aggregation:

```
select c3,
       (case when group_concat(c2 order by c1 desc) like 'B,%'
             then 'Valid'
             else 'Invalid'
        end) as flag
from t
group by c3;
```